# RSACryptoServiceProvider .Net 2.0 and Windows 10 Home

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, .net-2.0

Just looking for some explanation on why for Windows Home running as a normal level user this code fails for .Net 2.0 (this is something that braking in a legacy app i'd like to get onto Windows 10).

```
cspParam = new CspParameters { Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore };
_rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParam);
result = _rsa.ToXmlString(false);
Console.Write(result);
Console.ReadKey();
```

This runs fine on Windows 10 Pro .Net 2.0 and In comparability mode Windows 8.
Any detail on this would be a grate help thanks.

The line that's errors is

```
result = _rsa.ToXmlString(false);
```

But I think it's

```
cspParam = new CspParameters { Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore };
```

That is broken

Comment: What does "fails" mean? Exception? Invalid result? Something else?

Comment: That a good point in this case it is throwing an exception when i dose not on windows 10 pro or windows 8 comparability mode also works when run as admin just a normal level user on windows 10 home an exception is thrown when using CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore as a flag

Comment: Please update the question to specify exactly what line of code throws, and add the details of the exception (type, exact message).

Comment: I have updated and thanks for your time on this